# CLEAR_TOP + start new activity. Hierarchy issue

Tags: android

I have a hierarchy consisting of 4 levels of depth. My profile has the 2nd level of hieararchy that means that pressing back while being in the profile must always return user to the 1st hierarchy level.

My problem is that link to the profile is available on all levels; so, for instance, if a user being on the 4th level clicks on the profile link his hierarchy position must be changed to the 2nd level - NOT to the 5th.

I suppose there must be an essential way of doing it. So far I've come up with combination of `CLEAR_TOP to the 1st level + if(extra){startActivity(Profile)}` but in this way the 1st level activity will get recreated - right ? and that's why I want you to suggest something better.

Thanks guys :)

UPD: just to clarify a bit: there might not be an instance of Profile available, so simply clearing the top won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent 1st level MainActivity from recreating instead of plain `CLEAR_TOP` I added `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) MainActivity gets `onNewIntent` invoked in case it has been already created.

Having done that I can `switch` on Intent data and launch any 2nd level activity

Comment: Don't forget to change the launch mode of the activity from the default. If you don't do that it will be recreated anyway. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 0):

When you create the intent to go back to your MainActivity, you can set both flags, for `CLEAR_TOP` and `NEW_TASK`. This way it should bring back the existing activity if it is there, or otherwise create a new one.

```
.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```